# what is the time complexity of this method which checks if a number k can be represented as n^p

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Time complexity of below method? I'm calculating it as log(n)*log(n)= **log(n)**

```
public int isPower(int A) {
    if (A == 1) 
        return 1;

    for (int i = (int)Math.sqrt(A); i > 1; i--){
        int p = A;

        while (p % i == 0) {
            p = p / i;
        }

        if (p == 1) 
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you want k = n*p or k = n^p ?

Comment: @GolamMazidsajib good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You iterate from `sqrt(A) to 2`. Then u tried to factorize. For prime number your code iterate sqrt(A) times . its best case. if number is 2^30 then ur code execute
sqrt(2^30) * 30 means sqrt(n) * log(n) times.

So your code complexity: `sqrt(n) * log(n)`

Answer (score 3):

Worst-case complexity:

`for(..)` runs `sqrt(A)` times

Then `while(..)` depends on prime factorization of `A=p_1^e1*p_2^e_2*..*p_n^e_n`, so it is `Max(e_1,e_2,..,e_n)` worst-case, or roughly `Max(log_p_1(A),log_p_2(A),..)`

At most `while(..)` will execute `log(A)` times roughly.

so total rough worst-case complexity = `sqrt(A)*log(A)` leaving out constant factors

Worst-case complexity happens for numbers `A` which are products of different integers ie `A = n_1^e_1*n_2^e_2*..`

Average-case complexity:

Given than numbers which are products of different integers are more numerous than numbers which are simply powers of a single integer, in a given range, then choosing a number at random, is more likely to be product of different integers, ie `A = n_1^e_1*n_2^e_2..`. Thus average-case complexity is roughly the same as worst-case complexity ie `sqrt(A)*log(A)`

Best-case complexity:

Best-case complexity happens when the number `A` is indeed a power of a single integer/prime ie `A = n^e`. Then the algorithm in this case takes less time. I leave it as an exercise to compute best-case complexity.

PS. Another way to see this is to understand that checking if a number is a power of a prime/integer, effectively one has to factor the number to its prime factorisation (which is what is done in this algorithm), which is effectively of the same complexity (see for example [complexity of factoring by trial division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division#Speed)).

**SO should have mathjax support as cs.stackexchange has :p !**